# Android: Edit value inside xml at runtime

Tags: android, xml

I know after searching editing xml at runtime seems not possible

I want to change value of iconmask and scale inside appfilter.xml from res/xml/ at runtime

```
<resources>
<version>1</version>

    <iconmask img1="iconmask" /> ----> This one

    <scale factor="0.75" /> ----> And this one

</resources>
```

Is that possible? Or is there any alternative?

**Example**

After button cick I want to change this

```
<iconmask img1="iconmask" />

<scale factor="0.75" />
```

to this

```
<iconmask img1="iconmask_2" />

<scale factor="1.10" />
```

Comment: What is appfilter.xml used for? You could save the required values into a shared preference or any other persistent storage and then look it up at runtime or at a later stage.

Comment: That's a theme, it's like launcher read some preference from appfilter.xml inside res/xml/. Instead of having 2 different apk with different preferences I'm just trying to merge it and create some options

Comment: Perhaps you could save the default theme in the xml. During the first run of the app, create the other options or user defined options and save it the local storage. Something on the lines of [load default theme] and then [override with user defined values]

Comment: No, that's not app theme, it's launcher theme, like GO Launcher and ADW Launcher

Comment: These options that you have; can the end-user change them or will they remain the same always?

Comment: Take a look above, I have added more details

Comment: Those are properties that can be set in runtime, the best approach is to save the change with sharedpreference and then load from it, and use default values (from xml) if there's no custom changes.

Comment: Try this - save the changes in the shared preference. When you load up the app or the launcher, it would load all the values from the xml file. Once that is done, it would go through your shared preference and override the modified ones.

Comment: I still don't get it, how to replace the value of iconmask and scale?

Comment: @LuisAlberto It's hard to explain what I want. There's 2 apk, A & B. A read appfilter.xml from B (inside res/xml/). I don't have control to A, I just create B. So I can't make any changes in A, A only read appfilter.xml